# lost of local work after git stash command, how to retrive

Tags: git, github

I lost local work file after using 'git stash' command. unfortunately I didn't use git add and by mistake I lost my all work on local. Is there any way to retrieve these file in git.

Comment: These files were untracked?

Answer (score 1):

If the files were not tracked then running `git stash` wouldn't touch them.

EDIT: If you run `git stash -u` it will stash both tracked and untracked files.

If they were tracked regardless of whether they were staged or not they're currently stashed. To put these files and changes back you can either run `git stash pop` which will pop them and remove them from your stash stack. Or you can run `git stash apply` which will apply the changes without deleting them from the stack.

Comment: `git stash` has a `-u` option that will stash untracked files as well as tracked.  But otherwise your answer should work.

Comment: @Schleis nifty, will update my answer to reflect that. Thank you.